# How to tell whether my element needs innerHTML or value

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, abtest

I am using JavaScript to run some AB tests on my site. I am able to change the text in my `<button>`'s with `element.innerHTML = "Text that I want"` but using that same strategy I cannot change the text in `<input type="submit">`'s.

Inversely, I can change the value of submit buttons using `element.value = "Text that I want"`, but cannot change a `<button>`'s text in that way.

So my question is, how can I know which function needs to be used on a specific element so that I can create an algorithm that handles every type of element?

In short: How do I know whether to use `element.innerHTML` or `element.value` programmatically?

**NOTE:** jQuery is not allowed.

Example - Here is some code that takes a class name as input and changes the element throughout the page. Sometimes an `<input>` may have the identifying class, but sometimes it may be a `<div>`, `<button>` or `<p>`.

```
var execute = function(experimentName, variation){
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(experimentName);
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
            if (typeof(variation) == "function")
            {
                variation.call(elements[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                elements[j].value = variation;
                //elements[j].innerHTML = variation;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to do it in a generic way you could make an `instanceof` check against the input element's [interface class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

```
if( element instanceof HTMLInputElement ){
    element.value = "foo";
} else {
    element.innerHTML = "foo";
}
```

Comment: Great approach.You took it to next level.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you know how to use that element in HTML in the first place.

`innerHTML` sets the element's contents; `value` sets the element's `value=""` attribute.

Comment: How can I change the `value` of a `submit` and the `innerHTML` of a `button` with the same code?

Comment: There are only a few elements that use `value`, so you can just make a list and have an exception for them.

Comment: @MightyPork fair enough, I thought there may have been a more elegant way.